# SSRS - match dataset values with hard-coded values

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-tablix, rdl

I am trying to create an RDL file and I need a `tablix` to appear in the following format.

#### This is how I want the results to look

[image: This is how I want the results to look]

The values that are in bold are hard coded values. This is how the output from the `SELECT` statement in the datasets looks

#### SQL Output

[image: SQL Output]

I don't know how to make the values that output from the database match with the hard coded values in the RDL file. The 'Day' field represents a day in the month and the 'Num' field represents the number of sales that were on the day. The above example shows that on the first day of the month, there were 100 sales made. I need the `tablix` to output in that specific format.

If the day isn't in the SQL output (no sales made that day), I want it to output blank and/or 0.

Any idea how this could be accomplished?

Comment: what do you mean by hardcoded values in the RDL? Do you have a dataset that returns these values? if all you want to do is to return the report as 3 columns instead of one long list.. go to Report Properties - Columns- change from 1 to 3.. ( on the right had property pane)

Comment: It would appear that a "calendar" has been created and the values returned should sit in the respective number column that corresponds to the date.

Comment: Do you have access to the SQL, how is the "day" stored in the database

Comment: Like @JonTout is suggesting top side; use the date field in your sql server as you are clearly aggregating [Num] column based day. Get just the day part out from datepart function and your aces. You wont have to worry about 30, and 31 based month.

Answer (score 0):

Use a CTE to create rows for each day you need and then join your results on. A starting point for you CTE could be:

```
;WITH nums AS
   (SELECT 1 AS value
    UNION ALL
    SELECT value + 1 AS value
    FROM nums
    WHERE nums.value <= 30)
SELECT *
FROM nums
```

You'll probably then want to modify the total days based on the month you are viewing.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using lookups, but you would need to hard code a lookup in each cell. e.g. for day 1

```
=lookup(cint(1),Fields!Day.Value,Fields!Num.Value,"Dataset1")
```

A faster way would be to create a tablix on the dataset filtered on the first ten days:

```
=Switch(
Fields!DAY.Value <= 10 and Fields!DAY.Value >=1,"Include",
True,"Exclude"
)
```

Create a row group on days, then create a column with day and num, and columns with Fields!DAY.Value+10 and Fields!DAY.Value+20 with the following lookups:

```
=lookup(Fields!DAY.Value+10,Fields!DAY.Value,Fields!NUM.Value,"DataSet1")
=lookup(Fields!DAY.Value+20,Fields!DAY.Value,Fields!NUM.Value,"DataSet1")
```